# Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

Can someone tell me why this error would show up in this canned code I am using from SF's dev site?   Enterprise Release 12 of SF....

- Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types:
  Schema.SObjectField, String at line 50 column 42

  ```
  Lead dup1 = new Lead(LastName='Test1Dup',
                     Company='Test1Dup Inc.',
                     Email='test1@duptest.com');
  try {
    insert dup1;
    System.assert(false);
   } catch (DmlException e) {
    System.assert(e.getNumDml() == 1);
    System.assert(e.getDmlIndex(0) == 0);
    System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0).size() == 1);
    System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0)[0] == 'Email');
    System.assert(e.getDmlMessage(0).indexOf(
       'A lead with this email address already exists.') > -1);
  }
  ```

I am not even clear on the use of System.assert at all, and I've proven to myself that I have next to no clue on what to do to rectify this.  :-(

The error is referencing the "System.assert(false)" line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line provoking the error is actually

```
System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0)[0] == 'Email');
```

The error is complaining that you're comparing a `Schema.SObjectField` value with a `String`, which isn't allowed. It looks like `getDmlFields()` has changed over the releases. I'll raise a doc bug to get that example code fixed. Changing that line to

```
System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0)[0].getDescribe().getName() == 'Email');
```

should fix the error.

[`System.assert(condition)`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm) is used in test code to check that a given condition is true. If the condition is false, the test as a whole fails, and the location of the failure is given in the test output log.

Working through the asserts in that example:

- `System.assert(false);` says that you should never get to that line - the insert is expected to throw an exception.
- `System.assert(e.getNumDml() == 1);` says that the failure concerns a single record
- `System.assert(e.getDmlIndex(0) == 0);` says that the failure was on the very first inserted record
- `System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0).size() == 1);` says that the failure was caused by a single field in the offending record
- `System.assert(e.getDmlFields(0)[0].getDescribe().getName() == 'Email');` says that offending field is called 'Email'
- `System.assert(e.getDmlMessage(0).indexOf(
   'A lead with this email address already exists.') > -1);` says that the error message should match the expected value.

Basically, the test method is checking that the trigger executed EXACTLY as intended!

The exception methods, such as `getNumDml()`, are listed [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm).

Comment: Thank you VERY much.   I was pretty sure that this was related to this code being released (let's say) with r7, and we're on r12, so now it's broken.  (sigh)

Comment: This takes me back to my "original" error though.  The new code does allow me to keep the Email lines in (great!)...

When testing Apex in Sandbox, I get:

Error Message System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
Stack Trace Class.leadDupePreventerTests_v2.testLeadDupPreventer: line 45, column 1

L45, C1  =   System.assert(false);   (from the above code)

Any clue there..?   :-/  Ugh.

Comment: (I need to get in the habit of formatting Added Comments more cleanly, once I figure it out)

Comment: Error Message System.AssertException: Assertion Failed

Comment: Stack Trace Class.leadDupePreventerTests_v2.testLeadDupPreventer: line 45, column 1

Comment: Yes - that first assert(false) will fail, since the insert is succeeding.

Comment: Ugh.  So how does this help in the case of using this as a test class since I can't deploy?   :-/   What am I missing here?  I feel like I've totally overlooked something basic.

Comment: The Lead object that's being inserted is supposed to cause an error in the trigger, presumably because it's a duplicate with a record inserted earlier in the testmethod. However, it's not causing the error, which probably means the Lead isn't really a duplicate. Make sure both Leads have the same email address.

Comment: The basic problem is that you're changing how the trigger works, so you'll have to change how the test works, to match. Whatever your trigger now does - create a record somewhere else with the dupe, or whatever - you'll need to test in the test method.

Comment: I appreciate the input... going to work on it some more tomorrow.   I wish I could just be sent for formal Apex DEV 401 and 501 (or even just 501), but that's not possible at this time.

Comment: Definitely do 401 before 501 - the latter won't make much sense at all without the former!

Comment: @AMM - btw - it's good practice here to hit the 'accept' tick box thingie if you feel I've answered the question as you stated it.

Comment: I can only assume Chrome is hiding such a checkbox/etc from me.  Even CTRL-F is not showing me anything with "Accept" in it that would mark this answered.  :-/

Comment: @AMM - you should be able to click the hollow checkmark - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158765